# Загрузка изображений в vk пост wall.post

Tags: python, вконтакте

Появилась задача, выкладывать посты с прикрепленными фотографиями. При этом фотографии так же должны загружаться автоматически, подскажите, как выкладывать изображения в vk и прикреплять к посту?

Answer (score 0):

Для прикрепления фотографии к посту необходимо загрузить ее на сервер. Для этого можете воспользоваться документацией [2. Загрузка фотографий на стену](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=1.%2B%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%2B%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%2B%D0%B2%2B%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC). После загрузки ее уже можно прикрепить к посту в *wall.post*.

В библиотеке **vk_api** на Python можно посмотреть как это делается или воспользоваться готовым методом [vk_api.upload.VkUpload.photo_wall](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload.html#vk_api.upload.VkUpload.photo_wall).